# Is the following Bootstrap html structure acceptable

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to know if there is any problem if we do the following using bootstrap 3 with the html structure?

After reading the documentation and some examples all of them recommend doing the following structure

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-4" ></div>
   <div class="col-lg-4" ></div>
   <div class="col-lg-4" ></div>
</div>
```

but we are using angular in our application and the sizes of each panel could change and also each panel have it's own controller that knows when to expand or not. I already thought about a controller or an state manager but i don't know at the moment the final ui definitions.

So my question is is any problem with the following structure?

```
     <div class="row">
       <div>
          <div class="col-lg-4" ></div>
       </div>
       <div>
          <div class="col-lg-4" ></div>
       </div>
       <div>
          <div class="col-lg-4" ></div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you don't know about structure as a developer you shouldn't be messing with angular...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That structure is fine. However there is a mistake in your class names. It should be 'col-lg-4'.

It may also pay to use some other col-*-* classes to handle what happens on smaller devices/screen sizes

EDIT: 
After re-reading the question I see that they won't have fixed sizes. Perhaps consider implementing a function to assign different sizes to different elements.

E.G.

```
<div class="row">
   <div id="one"></div>
   <div id="two"></div>
   <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

Now you can reference the divs with the different id's and do something like this:

```
//if you want a large middle column with two smaller columns on the side
$('#one).addClass('col-lg-2'); 
$('#two').addClass('col-lg-8');
$('#three).addClass('col-lg-2');
```

note: I'm using jquery for that.

Comment: Yes i know about that, this is just an extract that, we have all the styles and some hidden classes to avoid displaying them on cellphones
So there is no problem with the css inheritance and nothing like similar (i'm not a designer)  with the structure?

Comment: @ManuFunes See updated answer, is that more like what you want?

Comment: Thanks, yes we have the idea of having a service that will handle this with angularjs via a mediator and some message between controllers but what worries me is that i didn't find any example of this structure in bootstrap

Comment: @ManuFunes Yeah fair enough, it's always daunting if you can't find examples of what you want. Remember though that trying things and making mistakes is the best way to learn! I'm no angular expert but the bootstrap structure if fine as long as you implement something to add classes to specify what sizing you want

If you found this helpful, feel free to mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score -1):

The grid class should be `col-lg-4` instead of `col-lg 4`.

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/